# How to iterate through a while loop of parameters to return the sum?

Tags: bash

```
if test $# -lt 1
then
        echo "Please input a valid amount of numbers. Need at least one."
        exit 1
else
        args=0
        while args -eq "$#"; do
                echo $args
                shift
        done
fi

echo $sum
echo $n
```

The error I'm receiving is

`./whileParamList: 15: ./whileParamList: args: not found`

The while loop will increment to the previous parameter with a `+=`

Comment: `args=o` does not look good.

Comment: meant to be a `0` sorry about that.. .still not the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this i think it is ok:

```
if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]
then
        echo "Please input a valid amount of numbers. Need at least one."
        exit 1
else
        n=$#
        sum=0
        for arg in "$@"
        do
          echo "$arg"
          sum=$(($sum+$arg))
        done
fi

echo "sum=$sum"
echo "number of parameters=$n"
```

If you prefer the parameter shift method, this also work:

```
if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]
then
        echo "Please input a valid amount of numbers. Need at least one."
        exit 1
else
        n=$#
        sum=0
        while [[ $# -ne 0 ]];
        do
          echo "arg=$1"
          sum=$(($sum+$1))
          shift
        done
fi

echo "sum=$sum"
echo "number of parameters=$n"
```

Comment: @ChrisZog Updated. Offcourse you can use the test method in `if then else` if you prefer so.

Comment: This code may *work* but it is unidiomatic in the extreme.  Bash is not C.  Use pipes, globs, [IFS](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341359/135943), and avoid explicit loops and index variables wherever possible.  Also, you don't need an "else" after "exit 1"; just put a "fi" and go forward.

Answer (score 3):

Bash isn't designed for numerical calculations.  It's an *orchestrator*, not a "language" in the sense that C or Python is.  See more detail:

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)

---

The way I would do this would be something like:

```
mysum() (
  IFS=+
  bc<<<"$*"
)
```

Or perhaps:

```
mysum() (
  IFS=+
  echo "$(($*))"
)
```

Then call it like so:

```
$ mysum 5 89 83 7 0 2
186
```