# Sum of the array is not printing

Tags: bash, shell-script, array

I am trying to create a script where the sum of the array is what prints but my results just end up showing me "Sum: 0"

Here is my script so far.

Any help in correcting this would be appreciated.

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -a array1={1 2 3 4}

#read array 
read -a array1

#set sum to zero 
sum=0

#loop for sum in array

for i in ${array1[@]}; do

  let sum+=$i

done

#print

echo "Sum: $sum"
```

Comment: The `declare` doesn't work, array assignments take parenthesis, not braces, though you're not using the assigned array anyway, since you `read` over it. Also you should quote the array expansion, `"${array1[@]}"`. But other than that, it does count the sum of the values entered, I don't see a problem in that.

Comment: Aside from which, this really isn't what shell scripts are for.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/341359/135943

Answer (score 2):

An array require the use of `(…)` in bash.
The array doesn't need to be read if it was already declared.
The `${array[@]}` expansion require quotes to work correctly:

```
declare -a array1=(1 2 3 4)

sum=0
for i in "${array1[@]}"; do
  ((sum+=$i))
done
echo "Sum: $sum"
```